# Curl POST request with an array of strings as a paramter

Tags: bash, curl

I want to send a curl post request with query params. One of these params is an array of strings. An example for such a string (using Postman chrome extension):

`http://www.example.com/my_rest_endpoint?start=123456&duration=11&array_param=["activity level"]`

Now, how can I translate this request to a curl command? no matter what I do, I can't seem to send the last parameter, `array_param` to curl. I've tried escaping the quotes and/or brackets with `\`, tried using `-i` flag and other various options, all with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was very close to what benaryorg suggested: Brackets and spaces needs to be placed with %5B, %5D and + according to the [url encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters). The quotes were escaped using \". The final result is:

`http://www.example.com/my_rest_endpoint?start=123456&duration=11&array_param=%5B\"Activity+Level\"%5D"`.

Comment: Turns out there's no standard encoding of array of strings. It seems the awful `array_param%5B%5D=Activity+Level` is more likely to work. See https://willhaley.com/blog/url-array-go/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried placing `'` around the parameters instead of escaping?

Also if that does not work, you could try to escape them like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29#Use_for_submitting_web_forms) example from Wikipedia.

You can find the codes for encoding [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters).